# R shiny, how to add a plot in a column

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I want to plot 3 measurements so that the user gets a feeling of the dispersion.
I created a R shiny app using the following code:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

fluidRow(
h2("Enter 3 values"),
column(width=2,offset=0, numericInput("triceps.sf1", label = "1.", value = 0)),
column(width=2,offset=0, numericInput("triceps.sf2", label = "2.", value = 0)),
column(width=2,offset=0, numericInput("triceps.sf3", label = "3.", value = 0)),
column(width=8,offset=0, plotOutput("sfTricepsPlot"))
 )
)#fluidpage
)#shinyUI
```

and the server code, where each measurement is plotted as a cross:

server.R

```
library(graphics)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

###################################
## Plot the values of sf measured
sfPlot <- function( m1, m2, m3 ){

par(mai = c(0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.8))
plot(1, axes=F, xaxt = "n", xlab = "Mesures", ylab = "sf (mm)", xlim = c(0.8, 3.2), ylim=c(0.8*m1, 1.2*m1))
axis( 1, at=1:3 )
axis(2, at=seq(from=0.8*m1, to=1.2*m1, by=10))
points( x=1, y=m1, pch=4, lwd=2, cex=1.5 )
points( x=2, y=m2, pch=4, lwd=2, cex=1.5 )
points( x=3, y=m3, pch=4, lwd=2, cex=1.5 )
}

######################################
## Plot the triceps sf
output$sfTricepsPlot <- renderPlot({
sfPlot(input$triceps.sf1, input$triceps.sf2, input$triceps.sf3)
})
})
```

You will see that the plot appears below the line where the input values are required.
How can I have that plot lying rather on the right side?
My goal is indeed to have many input lines in the final code, having the plots on the right side would make the page more compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `offset` parameter of the `column` function.

```
column(width=8,offset=4, plotOutput("sfTricepsPlot"))
```

Remember that the screen's width is 12 units, so if you intend to put an 8 unit UI element to the farthest right position, use `offset = 4`

Edit: In that case, you can just specify the height of the columns. (I changed the numericInput's width to 1, so that the 3 inputs + output width is <= 12. Otherwise they get split into 2 rows)

```
column(width=1,offset=0, div(style = "height:150px;"), numericInput("triceps.sf1", label = "1.", value = 0)),
column(width=1,offset=0, div(style = "height:150px;"), numericInput("triceps.sf2", label = "2.", value = 0)),
column(width=1,offset=0, div(style = "height:150px;"), numericInput("triceps.sf3", label = "3.", value = 0)),
column(width=8,offset=0, plotOutput("sfTricepsPlot"))
```

Comment: changing the offset moves the plot to the right side, but it still lies below the first row, I would like the three input tabs and the plots to be (as much as possible) in the same row

Answer (score 0):

The CSS framewok used by Shiny [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is based on a responsive grid layout:

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.

The columns per row can only have a max width of 12. In your example, your total is 2+2+2+8, which is 14. It means your last column will appear below the others. You can change `width=8` to `width=6` to fix your issue.